# Golang equivalent of strtotime("this Sunday, 23:59:59")

Tags: go, time, web-scraping

I am writing a scraper that scrapes offers off websites and these offers have end dates. One such website has offers that expire every Sunday. I have gone through the golang time documentation but still dont get how that can be done the equivalence I found in PHP and is pretty simple.

`$endDate = strtotime('this Sunday, 23:59:59');`

Is there a golang way to do this?

Comment: Take a look at package time.

Comment: [time.Parse()](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Parse)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write a function in Go using the [Go standard library time package](https://golang.org/pkg/time/). For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func endDate(t time.Time, wd time.Weekday) time.Time {
    next := int((wd - t.Weekday() + 7) % 7)
    y, m, d := t.Date()
    return time.Date(y, m, d+next+1, 0, 0, 0, -1, t.Location())
}

func main() {
    now := time.Now().Round(0)
    fmt.Println(now, now.Weekday())

    end := endDate(now, time.Sunday)
    fmt.Println(end, end.Weekday())
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/T0oZGRO9NV8

Output:

```
2018-11-08 05:25:01.104445722 -0500 EST Thursday
2018-11-11 23:59:59.999999999 -0500 EST Sunday
```

Comment: Thank you peterSO. It works perfectly. You definitely understand what I required.